# Persistent GPU shared memory

Tags: cuda, gpu, persistent, gpu-shared-memory

I am new to CUDA programming, and I am mostly working with shared memory per block because of performance reasons. The way my program is structured right now, I use one kernel to load the shared memory and another kernel to read the pre-loaded shared memory. But, as I understand it, shared memory cannot persist between two different kernels.

I have two solutions in mind; I am not sure about the first one, and second might be slow.

- First Solution: Instead of using two kernels, I use one kernel. After loading the shared memory, the kernel may wait for an input from the host, perform the operation and then return the value to host. I am not sure whether a kernel can wait for a signal from the host.
- Second solution: After loading the shared memory, copy the shared memory value in the global memory. When the next kernel is launched, copy the value from global memory back into the shared memory and then perform the operation.

Please comment on the feasibility of the two solutions.

Comment: Why do you need to wait for a host input after launch the kernel?

Comment: It sounds like you might be trying to shoehorn shared memory into a usage that it's not really meant for. If you are targeting a device of compute capability >= 2.0, I would say, don't worry about using shared memory at all, at first. Instead, set a preference for the L1 cache with `cudaFuncSetCacheConfig(MyKernel, cudaFuncCachePreferL1)`. When your algorithm is working, run your app in a CUDA profiler and check if it is memory bound. If it is memory bound, then consider if there is any way you can increase performance by using shared memory or using L1 more efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a variation of your proposed first solution: As you already suspected, you can't wait for host input in a kernel - but you can syncronise your kernels at a point. Just call "__syncthreads();" in your kernel after loading your data into shared memory.

I don't really understand your second solution: why would you copy data to shared memory just to copy it back to global memory in the first kernel? Or would this first kernel also compute something? In this case I guess it will not help to store the preliminary results in the shared memory first, I would rather store them directly in global memory (however, this might depend on the algorithm).